# Use Slicer selection in calculated column (Parameter)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have: 
- a slicer with dates and a table 'Log' with a column 'Date' with dates and a column 'Max' with numbers (e.g. 0,31)

I need to calculate the average of all values in the column 'Max' when the date is before the slicer selection date - and an average for after.

End result: a Card visualisation with the average of all values before the selected date and a Card visualisation with the average of all values after the selected date.

Comment: I think you don't need the calculated column. In you question says you have two, both called **Log**. Add some sample data and your expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create three measures:

```
avg = AVERAGE('Log'[Max])
```

```
AverageAfterSelectedDate =
CALCULATE (
    [avg],
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Log' ), [Date] > MINX ( 'Log', 'Log'[Date] ) )
)
```

```
AverageBeforeSelectedDate =
CALCULATE (
    [avg],
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Log' ), 'Log'[Date] < MINX ( 'Log', [Date] ) )
)
```

Just use the `AverageBeforeSelectedDate` and `AverageAfterSelectedDate` measures in the cards.

For this data:

[image]

It produces:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I cannot make it work: The formula editor won't let me select the field with  the date used in the slicer. I can select fields from the Log table and calculated columns/measures in the SharePoint table (where the slicer date is), but not the field I need. The slicer date is in another table than the Log.

Comment: I moved som stuff around and made it work. Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: A sidequestion... I have two more slicers active on the same db. These two do not affect the averages at the moment. Is it possible to extend the solution to include more slicers?

Answer (score 0):

I had to calculate count of all Accounts that were opened before the selected Slicer Date.

Here is what I ended up doing

```
TotalAccounts = 
CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1.ID),
           FILTER( 
                    ALL(Table1),MIN(Table2.Date)>Table1.Date)
                 )
```